# Object reference not set to an instance of an object List error C#

Tags: c#

Here's the line that has the error:

```
programs.Add(subkey.GetValue("DisplayName").ToString());
```

programs is a `List<string>`

The error is Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: Did you say `List<string> programs = new List<string>()` at any point?

Comment: This is probably happening because `programs` is never initialized. You should have a line somewhere that reads something like this: `programs = new List<string>();`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are three possibilities that you need to check.  Something has a value of `null`:

1. programs
2. subkey
3. the result of subkey.GetValue

It may be a bug in your code (eg, you forgot to instantiate `programs`); or something that you need to check at runtime.  For example, if `GetValue` possibly returns null, then you need something like this:

```
var val = subkey.GetValue("DisplayName");
if (val != null)
    programs.Add(val.ToString());
```